# How can i get the inserted seq without using the seq_name?

Tags: php, postgresql, psql

I'm re-developing an open-source program developed with **MySql** and re-writing an method like:

```
function lastid(){
    return mysql_insert_id($conn);
}
```

How can i perform this function using postgresql instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html
there is a function `lastval()` that

> Return the value most recently returned by nextval in the current
>   session. This function is identical to currval, except that instead of
>   taking the sequence name as an argument it fetches the value of the
>   last sequence that nextval was used on in the current session. It is
>   an error to call lastval if nextval has not yet been called in the
>   current session.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I want to confirm if it will work rewritten content like " function lastid(){return pg_query("select lastval()", $conn);} "

Comment: @藍劍樟 Just try it and see yourself.